# What does Per: Mean on an NDA?

Tags: contract-law, non-disclosure

I Have received an NDA I need to sign, it seems straight forward enough although there is one part i'm unsure of, on the last page there is the section where your witness signs, and you sign, but above that there is another section that looks like this.

```
(Company Who sent the NDAs name is above)

FakeCompany LTD

Per:_______________

Name:______________

Title:_____________
```

I've looked around online and have found some different suggestions although I couldn't find anything specific to this being on an NDA.

I think, it's for when you are signing on behalf of someone else but I'm not 100% sure so figured I would ask here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Latin - "through". It means that someone is signing on behalf of the company, and is not generally required but can be printed explicitly as evidence that the person signing purports to be authorised to do so.

Comment: What then is the expected difference of the "per" and "name" fields, then?

Comment: @sharur
 "Per" is for the signature, while "name" is for the printed name of the person signing on behalf of the company.

Comment: In U.S. business law the more common word to use would be "by" instead of "per", but they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

"Per" indicates that the person signing has the authority to bind the named signing entity (corporation, partnership or individual).